# "Could not find the main class, program will exit" while initializing class containing main()?

Tags: java

The class partially shown below contains a main method. When I run the code, I see a `NullPointerException` (NPE) and then an error message - "Could not find the main class, program will exit". My understanding is that if I get NPE, it means that the code is running, ie the JRE found a `main` method to begin execution, so why do I get the error message?

This is the console output

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.MyWorldDemo.getValue(MyWorldDemo.java:57)
at com.MyWorldDemo.<clinit>(MyWorldDemo.java:23)
Exception in thread "main"
```

In a nutshell:

- username is stored in a properties file.
- properties file is like this username=superman....etc

here is some code example

```
class MyClass {
    private final static String username = getData("username"); // ERROR HERE

    private static Properties prop;
    // more variables

    static {
        prop = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyDB.properties");
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // this method will assign a value to my final variable username.
    public static String getData(String props) {
        String property = prop.getProperty(props);// ERROR HERE !!!
        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please related code. I strongly suspect your main method syntax is wrong.

Comment: Can you show the console output.

Comment: It cannot find main ***class***, not main ***method***. Big difference. If you don't have a valid main method, Eclipse won't allow you to run your class as a program. I wonder if your Eclipse workspace is corrupt. Does any of your code work in Eclipse?

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - There are other programs that work correctly. Only this one is causing problems. It used to work properly before !

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I can't give the entire code - But i can tell you what i am trying to do in those two lines. Please refer to the new edits.

Comment: @everyone - why is this down voted  ? Why won't anyone give a reason for the down voting ? At least that will show me my error.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels and thanks man ! I think that my lame mistake could become a question for an exam or an interview :)

Comment: The only criticism I'd make to the question is that it wasn't very informative and was completely unanswerable when first presented. When you finally gave the necessary information, then it became answerable. My suggestion is that  you remember this for your next question. Good luck.

Comment: @Everyone - I am very sorry for the inconvenience i had caused. I am a little new to coding. I wrongly assumed that everything would be obvious even without code :(. Once again, I thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing of static variables depends on its position in code (variables are initialized from top to bottom). In your code

```
private final static String username = getData("username"); // ERROR HERE
private static Properties prop;
// more variables

static {
    prop = new Properties();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyDB.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`prop` object will be initialized after `username` in static block, but since to initialize `username` `prop` is necessary and its not initialized yet you get NPE. Maybe change your code to something like:

```
private static Properties prop = new Properties();
private final static String username = getData("username"); 

static {

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyDB.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me from a major headache.

Comment: Very nice, complete coverage of the issue, @Pshemo

Answer (score 2):

You have a static initialization at line 23 of `MyWorldDemo` that is calling the method `getValue`, which is then causing a NPE at line 57, therefore the class cannot be instantiated, therefore the main method cannot be called.  It probably looks something like:

```
class MyWorldDemo {
    private static String foo = getValue("username");
    private static Properties prop;

    // This happens too late, as getValue is called first
    static {
        prop = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyDB.properties");
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // This will happen before static initialization of prop
    private static String getValue(String propertyValue) {
        // prop is null
        return prop.getProperty(propertyValue);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello!"); // Never gets here
    }
}
```

Comment: nice guess. My code is a little different, but something similar happens in my code. Thanks !